# For loop exiting early while updating modified or new records in datatable.net table

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, datatables

I'm using the Datatables jQuery plugin.  The table is pulling the data from an AJAX source (a SQL Server query, processed by ASP.NET into a JSON object).  I want to create a live view of the table so that changes appear in real time.  But rather than reloading the entire table every few seconds with `fnReloadAjax()` (which, from experience, has proven to be quite burdensome on the browser) I'm only updating the records that are new or modified, using `fnAddData()` and `fnUpdate()`.

After getting a JSON object of just the new or modified records, here's my code to process the object.

```
        var newData = updatedDataJSON.aaData;

        if (newData[0] != null) {                
            for (i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {     //Loop through each object
                if (newData[i].bNewCase === true) {    //Process new cases
                    oTable.fnAddData(newData[i]);   
                } else {                              //Process modified cases   
                    var tableArray = oTable.fnGetData();
                    var index;
                    var found = false;
                    var serial = newData[i].serial;  
                    var dataObject = newData[i];

                    //First gotta find the index in the main table for 
                    // the record that has been modified.  This is done 
                    // by matching the serial number of the newData 
                    // object to the original aData set:

                    for (ii = 0; ii < tableArray.length; ii++) {
                        var value = tableArray[ii]['serial'];
                        value = value.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, ""); 
                        if (value === serial) {
                            index = ii;
                            found = true;                                
                        }
                    }
                    if (found) {
                        oTable.fnUpdate(dataObject, index);
                        console.log('Updated ' + newData[i].serial);
                    }                                         
                }
            }
        }
```

My problem is that even though the `newData.length` property of the first for loop could be greater than 1, the for loop exits early (after one iteration).  I added the `console.log` statement at the end and it started passing errors saying that `newData[i].serial` was undefined.  This makes me think that the entire newData array was destroyed or something...

I'm really hoping that I've just made a stupid mistake (though I've checked and checked and checked some more but can't find one).  Maybe there's something that I'm overlooking.  If anyone has any advice, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about changing `value = tableArray[ii]['serial']` to `value = tableArray[ii].serial`? Maybe it's a scope problem? Unless `i` and `ii` are declared somewhere else they should be declared within the scope of that function so `for (var ii = 0) ...`

Comment: where does `var newData = updatedDataJSON.aaData;` come from? Sounds like you are accessing data outside the ajax callback and AJAX is asynchronous

Comment: @elclanrs Your solution completely worked (it was a scope issue for declaring `i` and `ii`).  @charlietfl The data is pulled from a `$.ajax` request, and yes it is asynchronous.  And I am accessing the data outside the callback, using the `.responseText` property.  Is this a bad practice (and what would the alternative be)?  Thanks to both of you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to @elclarnrs for the solution, posted above in the comments.  The solution was declaring the values of `i` and `ii` in the scope of the function.  That got everything working smoothly.  Good to know for future reference.